# Postman POST request works fine but in Python it doesn't (Java Spring server, PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, http, python-requests

This is a bit of a broad question, since it has to do with both Java Spring and Python, but I can't really tell exactly where the error is due to the following reasons:

1. A POST request in Postman works just fine, no errors
2. A Python request using the requests library does not work, and returns error 400
3. In my Java Spring application, I can see the following in the terminal, after the POST attempt on Python: `Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of` [group].StatsDto `(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value [JSON STRING]`

code snippets on relevant files:

StatsDto.java
note: I tried not using that @JsonProperties annotation and the ones after, but got the same result.

```
public class StatsDto {

    @NotBlank
    private String codec;
    @NotBlank
    private String video;
    @NotBlank
    private String resolution;
    @NotNull
    private float fps;
    @NotNull
    private int nFrames;
    @NotNull
    private int qp;
    @NotNull
    private float yPSNR;
    @NotNull
    private float uPSNR;
    @NotNull
    private float vPSNR;
    @NotNull
    private float yuvPSNR;
    @NotNull
    private float bitrate;
    @NotNull
    private float time;

    public StatsDto() {
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public StatsDto(@JsonProperty("codec") String codec, @JsonProperty("video") String video,
                    @JsonProperty("resolution") String resolution, @JsonProperty("fps") int fps,
                    @JsonProperty("nFrames") int nFrames, @JsonProperty("qp") int qp,
                    @JsonProperty("yPSNR") float yPSNR, @JsonProperty("uPSNR") float uPSNR,
                    @JsonProperty("vPSNR") float vPSNR, @JsonProperty("yuvPSNR") float yuvPSNR,
                    @JsonProperty("bitrate") float bitrate, @JsonProperty("time") float time) {
        this.codec = codec;
        this.video = video;
        this.resolution = resolution;
        this.fps = fps;
        this.nFrames = nFrames;
        this.qp = qp;
        this.yPSNR = yPSNR;
        this.uPSNR = uPSNR;
        this.vPSNR = vPSNR;
        this.yuvPSNR = yuvPSNR;
        this.bitrate = bitrate;
        this.time = time;
    }
```

HttpContent.py

```
class HttpContent:

    (...)

    def POST(self) -> requests.Response:
        mock_dict = {
            "codec": "SVT-AV1",
            "video": "bowling_cif",
            "resolution": "800x600",
            "fps": 29.97,
            "nFrames": 300,
            "qp": 27,
            "yPSNR": 32.05,
            "uPSNR": 39.78,
            "vPSNR": 31.423,
            "yuvPSNR": 37.32193728,
            "bitrate": 2178327.32,
            "time": 83289382.3289
        }

        response = requests.post(self.base_url, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}, json=json.dumps(mock_dict))
        return response
```

app.py

```
http = HttpContent("[LINK]")

print(http.POST())
```

I tried changing annotations in the Java application, creating an empty Constructor and a full one, checking syntax in Python, hardcoding the dict as a string with str(), etc. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out the answer just minutes after asking, even though i had been looking for it for a while, luckily. Here's what I did, in case you run into the same problem:

I found out that Postman can generate code for your requests using the <> button on the right. Simply input the language and library you want to use and copy the code. In my case, that was Python / Requests. It gave me a code slightly dissimilar to the one i was using, but the main difference was that it used `data` as a parameter instead of `json` and the `requests.request("POST")` method instead of simply `requests.post()`.